# How to implement struct.unpack in Java with float type?

Tags: java, struct, unpack

I have a Python code that works fine but I will need to convert it into Java:

```
    file_path = ...
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        in = file.read(4 * 128 * 128)
        numbers = struct.unpack('f' * 128 * 128, in)
```

I found [the implementation for other types here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879009/how-to-convert-python-struct-unpack-to-java) but I am looking for the implementation of the struct.unpack in Java for [float type(C Type = f)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

Comment: Something like a `ByteBuffer` or a `FloatBuffer` seems possible here, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the bytes you read from the file in a [`FloatBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html).

```
var fis = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file");
var bytes = fis.readNBytes(4 * 128 * 128);
var floats = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
//  optionally, specify the byte order here
//  .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    .asFloatBuffer();
```

Then, you can use `floats.get(n)` to get the float at index `n`, or `floats.put(n, f)` to write the float `f` into index `n`, just like you can with a `float[]`.

If you want a `float[]` for some reason, you need to allocate a new one and read the contents of `floats` into it:

```
var floatArray = new float[128 * 128];
floats.get(floatArray);
```

Comment: I ran the above code and got different results from Python. I would expect to get these results like (18.477258682250977, 18.461912155151367, 18.826318740844727, 18.76152801513672,...) but I got these results from Java code: 
(8.107548E27, NaN, 3.28386592E8, -5.015591E-22, -5.2745868E-12, 2.7122066E24, 997716.06,...)

Comment: @newbie5050 Could it be because of the endianness? What endianness does your python code use? Specify that using the `order` method I showed.

Comment: It worked after I took your advice using. order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN). Appreciated!

Comment: I am trying to modify the above code into Double (for higher precision):         var doubles = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
//  optionally, specify the byte order here 
  .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asDoubleBuffer();
        var doubleArray = new double[128 * 128];
        doubles.get(doubleArray); but I got the error. Do you have an idea how to modify the code for double?

Comment: @newbie5050 are you still reading 4*128*128 bytes? That will be 128*64 doubles, not 128*12&. Doubles take up twice as much space.